Order Summary shows wrong label for discount after refreshing
I have modified the en_US.csv file on my site to change the word "Discount" to "Savings" in the Order Summary that displays on the cart page.
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv
"Discount","Savings"
"Discount (%1)","Savings (%1)"
Discount,Savings

In this clip, you can see that when the page initially loads the word "Savings" is there; however, when the Order Summary refreshes, the word "Discount" displays again.

When I step through the JS, it shows the title as having the word "Discount".
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/discount.js

When I look for the window.checkoutConfig in console and copy out that content, I can see that the title has "Savings" in it.


Where is it getting "Discount" from, when as far as I can tell, it should be showing "Savings"?
